# Using Vuetify/webpack-ssr template and cant get babel and eslint working

Tags: webpack

I just started a project with Vuetify and Vue, and am using the Webpack with Server Side Rendering template [template](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/webpack-ssr/tree/master/template/build).

I've been trying to get the spread operator to work, even though the buble config in the vue-loader specifies Object.assign, this still fails. I attempted to port to babel instead, adding babel-loader and eslint-loader to the loaders for vue and js files as follows in my webpack.base.config.js:

```
...

module: {
    noParse: /es6-promise\.js$/, // avoid webpack shimming process
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: ['vue-loader', 'babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
        options: vueConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {

        }
      },

...
```

**How do you manually add different loaders (transpilers and linters in this case) to your webpack config?**

Comment: I really don't understand your question - what's the problem?

Comment: @AndrewLi babel doesn't Transpile my code into ES6, even after changing my webpack config. I ditched buble for babel after I couldn't get it to transpile my spread operators.

Comment: Do you have your `.babelrc` setup?

Comment: @AndrewLi it's setup as the babel docs say @ https://babeljs.io

Comment: Essentially, I can't get babel and eslint to with the vuetify/webpack-ssr template out of the box.